# Is "there" often omitted in colloquial speech?

Tags: grammar, spoken-english, colloquial-language

I am reading Post Office by Charles Bukowski. The writing style of the book is quite conversational and colloquial.
This sentence came up in the book.

> I think he wanted to use the word “hygienics” somewhere but it
> simply wasn’t in him.

It sounds a little off to me. I think a "there" is omitted.

> I think he wanted to use the word “hygienics” somewhere but it
> simply wasn’t **there** in him.

This sounds a lot better to me.

Is it often omitted in coloquial speech?

Comment: There is no reason for the word **there** to be in that sentence.  Consider "The cat is in the box."  That's the more natural way to say it.  You *could* say "The cat is *there* in the box" but there isn't any particular reason to add it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it isn't particularly colloquial. *Not to have it in one to do something* is an established idiom - see [this](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/not%20have%20it%20in%20one)